# Является ли нора частным случаем гнезда?

Tags: семантика

Является ли нора (углубление в земле, служащее жильём) видом гнезда (построенное, оборудованное животным жилище)? Почему дырочка в стене называется мышиной норой, если нора есть углубление в земле?

Comment: И ос. (15 символов)

Comment: Ничего подобного, мыши тоже себе обустраивают гнезда, только они их не вьют и не лепят. ГНЕЗДО — 1. У птиц, насекомых, пресмыкающихся, **грызунов** и некоторых других животных: место жилья, кладки яиц и выведения детёнышей. https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/39738  Поселяясь рядом с человеком, домовые мыши устраивают свои гнёзда в самых укромных и защищённых уголках... Для гнезда используют любые доступные материалы: бумагу, клочки ткани, шерсть, перья, искусственные волокна. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%88%D1%8C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Является ли нора частным случаем гнезда?
```

Нет, конечно. Нора и гнездо - частные случаи жилища.  Гнездо -  место, обустраиваемое для укрытия, кладки яиц и выведения потомства у птиц, насекомых, животных на какой-то поверхности - на земле, на стене, на дереве или в замкнутом пространстве.

Нора – это жилище животного под землей в виде ямки с выходом наружу, т.е. тоннель.

```
 Является ли нора  видом гнезда ?
```

Видимо, нора в случае мышей - это только проход к гнезду, гнездо - специально обустроенное место, где животные растят и выводят своих детенышей.

Дырочка в стене, вероятно, называется мышиной норой, потому что вряд ли мышиная семейка будет в этой дырочке жить, здесь она будет выходить наружу на охоту за едой и водой, а жить будет где-то в обустроенном месте, поэтому дырочка в стене - начало тоннеля, норы. Мне так кажется, иначе нам было бы легко изничтожить эту семейку, а вот нор у них много, попробуй найди само лежбище.

Answer (score 0):

Гнездо — это **сооружение**, обычно из веток, травы. Но нора сооружением не является. Теоретически гнездо может находится в норе.

Да, мыши иногда живут в гнёздах — где выводят потомство.

[image]
[image]

И даже не в норе, а на каких-то растениях, как птицы, иногда в траве.

[image]
http://veganstvo.info/268-taynaya-zhizn-myshek-malyutok-v-pole-15-foto.html

Ответ с mail.ru: "На высоких травинках они делают круглые домики из той же травки".
https://otvet.mail.ru/question/27311468

Даже кабаны сооружают себе гнёзда.
[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Кабан](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD)

А некоторые животные просто живут в вырытых ими норах. Им не нужны сооружения.
Примеры из словаря:
*Лисья, барсучья нора.

По вечерам суслики выползают из нор.*